# Problem on application with ASP in IIS 7.5 with Oracle 11g

Tags: iis7, asp

We have an application developed with .Net on server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5 which is linked liked to Oracle 11g on another server. Our problem is that we lose the service every two or three or more. The application stops and we have to restart IIS or the server to continue the job (the number of users is less then 50). We have no error message. Do you know anything to do to avoid this situation,  something like:

- A parameter to put on ASP pages
- A parameter to switch on or off on the server or on the database

Comment: Your question belongs on serverfault, but we need more information before it's worth moving over. You say "every two or three or more", or more what? Minutes? Hours? Have you checked the event log? What do you want the parameter to do? Give you an error message? Stop it happening somehow?

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your answer, we lose the service every two or three (days) or more

Comment: Can you answer my other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to look at:

1. Recycle your app pools - set them to recycle based on x number of visits.  Its probably a memory leak that is causing this.
2. Turn on application tracing.  This will give you more detailed logs that will make it easier to diagnose your problem.
3. If your using ODBC to connect to oracle, make sure that you have ODBC connections configured correctly.  You can set ODBC max connections to what makes sense for your app.  If your ODBC connection runs out of memory then it will crash.
4. You can write a script to restart IIS every x hours.  With IIS we find that we need to restart IIS daily / windows servers weekly.  We use multiple IIS nodes behind a HaProxy server so that other iis servers take on the load during these brief restarts.
5. Make sure you are closing connections to the DB in your app.  Read Data, copy to local  varaibles, close connections.  That goes for both .net and classic asp.

Your best friend here is IIS advanced logging and failed request tracing.  It will give you a lot more detail on what is cooking versus IIS built in logs (which do nothing but take up space).